# subsonic 3.0 dynamic search query

Tags: subsonic3

I want to build dynamic search query with subsonic 3.0.
who can help me?
Any sample Please.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to do is add conditions to an IQueryable based on your dynamic parameters. For example:

```
string productName = Request.Querystring[ProductName];

IQueryable<Product> productQuery = Product.All();

if(productName != null)
{
  productQuery = productQuery.Where(product => product.Name == productName);
}

IList<Product> filteredList = productQuery.ToList();
```